# Lashon Hara in Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: shulchan-aruch, lashon-hara-slander

Why aren't the laws of lashon hara in the shulchan aruch? The Rambam talks about them in Hilchos De'os, but as far as I'm aware the shulchan aruch does not.

Comment: The question isn't really on the SA. The SA contains the conclusions of the Beth Yosef, which is itself really a commentary on the Tur. So the question is, why isn't it included in the Arba'ah Turim... and the simplest explanation would be that he likely didn't think it neatly fit topically in any of the four sections.

Comment: But wan't his goal to codify all of halacha that applies nowadays? So wouldn't he find somewhere to fit it in, as we know it's an important topic... I think one could argue quite easily it would fit into orach chayim as it's something you encounter on a day to day basis.

Comment: He left out many miswoth that are daily encountered (love of ones fellow, love of the convert, etc.). He seems to have not included things that fall under the rubric of Hilkhoth Deoth generally.

Comment: The MB (156) recognizing these deficiencies wrote: ועוד יש הרבה מצוות תדירות עשין ולאוין הנזכרת בכל ארבעה ספרי השולחן ערוך וימצא אותם המעיין כל אחד במקומו ועוד יש הרבה והרבה שלא הובאו בהשולחן ערוך ונמצאים בספרי מוני המצוות הרמב ם והסמ"ג והחינוך (וביותר בספר חרדים כי הוא קיבץ מכל הראשונים הקדומים לו במצוות הנוהגות בזמן הזה) ונכון מאוד שילמד אותם כל אדם ויהיה בקי בהן ועל ידי זה יהיה ביכולתו לקיימן וכמו שאמרו חז ל וראיתם אותו וזכרתם את כל מצוות ה ועשיתם אותם זכירה מביאה לידי עשייה דאם לא ידע אם היא מצוה כלל מה יזכור לקיימן